# Makefile: No rule to make target despite giving target?

Tags: c, makefile

While trying to use Make I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `paging.c', needed by `obj/paging.o'. Stop.
```

But I have given the makefile the rule for making the target. Here's my makefile:

```make
                                                                 --------
C_SOURCES= main.c monitor.c common.c descriptor_tables.c timer.c paging.c \
        fs.c initrd.c task.c syscall.c                           --------
S_SOURCES= boot.s interrupt.s gdt.s process.s
C_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c, obj/%.o, $(C_SOURCES))
S_OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.s, obj/%.o, $(S_SOURCES))
CFLAGS=-c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders
LDFLAGS=-Tlink.ld -melf_i386 --oformat=elf32-i386
ASFLAGS=-felf

all: kern/kernel

.PHONY: clean
clean:
-rm -f obj/*.o kern/kernel

kern/kernel: $(S_OBJECTS) $(C_OBJECTS)
ld $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

$(C_OBJECTS): obj/%.o : source/%.c 
gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

vpath %.c source

$(S_OBJECTS): obj/%.o : %.s
nasm $(ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

vpath %.s asem
```

NOTE: the `--------` is not in the original makefile, they are just used to pick the rule I have used.

make output:

```
nasm -felf asem/boot.s -o obj/boot.o
nasm -fenasm -felf asem/boot.s -o obj/boot.o
nasm -felf asem/interrupt.s -o obj/interrupt.o
nasm -felf asem/gdt.s -o obj/gdt.o
nasm -felf asem/process.s -o obj/process.o
gcc -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders source/main.c -o obj/main.o
gcc -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders   source/monitor.c -o obj/monitor.o
gcc -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders   source/common.c -o obj/common.o
gcc -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders source/descriptor_tables.c -o obj/descriptor_tables.o
gcc -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders source/timer.c -o obj/timer.o
make: *** No rule to make target `source/paging.c', needed by `obj/paging.o'. Stop.
```

Why is it coming out with the error despite giving it what it needs?

Comment: Your makefile works for me as written, provided I create the .c files in source and .s files in asem.  Perhaps you made a transcription error.  I would double check that the file "paging.c" actually exists in your "source" directory, with exactly that spelling/capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the line

```
$(C_OBJECTS): obj/%.o : %.c
```

to

```
$(C_OBJECTS): obj/%.o : source/%.c
```

edit, in reflect of question change:

```
void page_fault(registers_t regs)
void page_fault(registers_t *regs);
```

Compare ;) The two should be the same. According to the code chunk from paging.c, the version in paging.h should be corrected (just remove the *).

Comment: Still having the same error even with the edit to the makefile :L

Comment: Does the make process change working directory (e.g does it say "Entering directory...")?

Comment: yes it does it says the following: gcc -c -nostdlib -nostdinc -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m32 -Iheaders source/timer.c -o obj/timer.o

Comment: So it is going into the directories as should.

Comment: No, it doesn't. If it would, make would explicitly print "Entering directory XY". Could you paste the whole make output in your question please?

Comment: It really seems that source/paging.c does not exist. Does it?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file paging.c exist in the same directory as the Makefile?

If it does not, Make will look for a rule to create it.  Since there is no rule to create paging.c, it will give you this error.

Comment: No it exists in the directory "source", which is defined with 

    

    vpath %.c source

Comment: There appear to be some vpath directives, which make things more complex…

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that "make" cannot find the file "paging.c" anywhere in the vpath or in the current directory, and it has no rule to create "paging.c" from any other source file.

Make sure that you actually have "paging.c" where you think you do, and that it is actually called "paging.c" and not "paging.c " (extra space) or some other unicode special stuff that looks like "paging.c" when you print it out, but isn't.